# Stopping an Action to be accessible from outside an application

Tags: php, post, yii

I have a web application that has been coded in Yii.

One such module in the application has a classified page that has been coded using CListView. I have made some modifications to the **jquery.yiilistview.js** by which I am able to POST data to a particular action which inturn returns the next set of data items to be filled in the pagination view.

Now my question is, Is there any way I can secure my Action API so that it returns the data only if the request parameters have been posted by my site.

[ie: I dont want there to be a an "easy" way to get the data contained in my classifieds by using some sort of a cron or a CURL script or by any other mechanism]

Comment: Has been asked before. Answer is no, you will find more details if you search this site. Look for AJAX.

Comment: I am using AJAX, but the problem is using firebug or any other such tool one can see all the post parameters that are being sent, so I suppose one can easily spoof the request.

Comment: Yes one can, as written, the answer is no. You can continue to complain but if you're not able to search the site, I can't be of much help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Yii's [CSRF-Prevention Feature](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security#cross-site-request-forgery-prevention) although it is commonly used if you have a form to submit

Comment: I have seen this feature, but I am not sure how this will help me in this case. The thing is the YII_CSRF_TOKEN is also been sent along with the other post parameters. So I am thinking this can be spoofed as well.

Comment: My main concern is to protect data from being parsed, esp the data present as a part of the pagination.

Comment: As far as I know YII_CSRF_TOKEN changes automatically for every request. It can't be spoofed

Comment: Is it? I thought I saw it constant and remembered it being saved in a cookie.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. It is constant for the current session and stored in cookie. But you can set `'enableCookieValidation'=>true` in your application configuration so that nobody can tamper the cookie

Comment: But still, say I am a person who basically wants to parse the data out of the classifieds pagination. I can see whats the cookie value(via the first post cycle from the site) and just keep passing the same value again and again right?

Comment: Yes. Then you need to either authenticate the user or use a captcha form before showing the classified data  in order to avoid bots from accessing the page. Any content that is made public can be parsed by bots. So i recommend using a captcha or user authentication.

Comment: Or you can improve the security by user-agent verification, http-refferer verification etc etc

Comment: Ok, I will mark your answer as correct not because the answer is CSRF, but because of the points you have mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the IP address of the requester using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']? Only let the function run for your IP address. That way unless they spoof their IP you are safe.

Comment: How easy or difficult is it to spoof an IP address?